# atabase Migrations has stopped working

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, database-migration

I am really stuck at the moment.
When I put a Required attribute on a field, Update-Database did not work. I had to go to the database and drop a constraint and then it did work.
So problem solved. However since then all the changes I have tried to make have been ignored.
I get;

```
PM> Update-Database -Verbose
Using StartUp project 'SCD'.
Using NuGet project 'SCD.Model'.
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Target database is: 'SherryGreenGroup' (DataSource: SQL_MULALLEY, Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Configuration).
No pending code-based migrations.
Running Seed method.
PM>
```

It simply ignores the change I am making and nothing I can do will change that. Why would this be and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I found was that I moved the dll of my database project into a lib library, and this disrupted how Database Migrations works.